# Set callback for class method

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

For Slickgrid,

Normally you can set callback `dateFormatter` like this in `columns` variables.

```
var columns = [
   {id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish", 
    formatter: dateFormatter, // path callback name to table 
    sortable: true }
  ];

function dateFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    return value.getMonth() + '/' + value.getDate() + '/' + value.getFullYear();
}
```

Now I made the class which contained the member and method related to handling table.

Then, I want to catch `dateFormatter` callback in class method. How can set callback??

```
class Table{
   constructor(){
      this.columns = [
   { id: "finish", name: "Finish", 
     field: "finish", 
     formatter: `this.dateFormatter`}, // it doesn’t work
  ];
      this.data = new Array();
      this.dataView = new Data.DataView();
      this.grid; 
   }
   makeGrid(gridName){
      this.grid = new Grid(gridName,
      this.dataView, 
      this.columns,
      this.options);
   }
   dateFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) { // want to catch here.
        return value.getMonth() + '/' + value.getDate() + '/' + value.getFullYear();
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for backtick in formatter. Instead try this - formatter:this.dateFormatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a function reference as a template literal string.

Change

```
formatter: `this.dateFormatter`
```

To

```
formatter: this.dateFormatter
```

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor:

```
this.columns = [
   { id: "finish", name: "Finish", 
     field: "finish", 
     formatter: this.dateFormatter} // no need for back-ticks
  ];
```

No need for `back ticks` in `this.dateFormatter`, that will convert it into a string.